# How can i create a contact view interface in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i create a view like Contact book in android phones. Alphabets list on one side and while i tap on any alphabet it should go to the contacts of that particular alphabet. Any built in mechanism to make that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support from Android but you can do the same. 
See this link [sideindex](http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html)

Hope this helps..